# Logs - Simplifying with arbitrary constant

Tags: logarithms, constants

I've tried simplifying my answer, which has a constant in it. I would like to know if I am on the right track:
$$ \ln(y) = -{x^2\over 2y^2} + C $$
***C*** can be considered as an Arbitrary Constant. From this we can say that:

$$\ln(k) = C$$

We can further simplify the above to the following:
$$ y = k.e^\frac{-x^2}{2y^2} $$

Would this be correct?

Comment: yes it is right but you have the $y$ again of the right side of the equation

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Just wanted to check if I was correct w.r.t simplifying with the constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. To me, it is simpler to argue that
$$
y = \exp \left( -\frac{x^2}{2y^2}+C \right)
  = e^C \exp \left( -x^2/(2y^2) \right)
  = K e^{-x^2/(2y^2)},
$$
where $K$ is some constant since $C$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

We have, 
$$ \ln(y) = -{x^2\over 2y^2} + C $$
if $\ln(k) = C$ then 
$$ \ln(y) = -{x^2\over 2y^2} + \ln (k) $$ $$\implies \frac{x^2}{2y^2}=-\ln (y)+\ln(k)$$ $$\implies \frac{x^2}{2y^2}=\ln\left(\frac{k}{y}\right)$$ $$\implies \frac{k}{y}=e^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}$$ $$\implies \frac{y}{k}=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}$$ $$\implies y=k\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}$$
Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $C$ is a constant (meaning it does not change with any variable change), we can indeed substitute $C=\ln(k)$ for some other constant $k$. Though this constant is related to $C$, it is still a constant - because $C$ is in no way related to a variable, $C$ will not change, and neither will $k$. Your simplified form is thus correct.